# Hibernate executed queries and testing

Tags: hibernate, testing

Is there a way to find out what queries are executed with hibernate?

I would like to write a performance test to ensure only a specific query and amount are run.

**Update:** Just a clarification, i would like to programatically find out how many queries are run, not just via visual-manual inspection, so it would easily testable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable Hibernate statistics and use [`SessionFactory#getStatistics()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html#getStatistics%28%29) to retrieve a  [`Statistics`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/stat/Statistics.html) and access the metrics related to queries.

See [`getQueries()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/stat/Statistics.html#getQueries%28%29), [`getQueryStatistics(String)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/stat/Statistics.html#getQueryStatistics%28java.lang.String%29), [`QueryStatistics`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/stat/QueryStatistics.html) and the other methods.

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [3.4.6. Hibernate statistics](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-statistics)
  - [20.6. Monitoring performance](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-monitoring)

Comment: @Bozho Statistics are really full of nice metrics, very useful.

Comment: Your reference return 404

Answer (score 0):

hibernate.show_sql =true would show all the sqls executed.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html