# get SQL from hibernate get

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

Is there a way to get the SQL query from a `session.get(class name, id)` call? I saw this post earlier: [How to get SQL from Hibernate Criteria API (*not* for logging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554481/how-to-get-sql-from-hibernate-criteria-api-not-for-logging) but it does not cover get queries.

Clarification: I am looking for an API method to get the query string, not from the query log. In other words I am asking if there is a method (like `toSql` below) where instead of:

```
Foo foo = session.get(Foo.class, id);
```

I can say something like:

```
String sqlOrHql = session.get(Foo.class, id).toSql();
// execute sqlOrHql to get foo, either through hibernate or manually using JDBC
```

Comment: Note that it should be more complicated than getting SQL from criteria query for the following reasons: 1)If your entity has relationships with other entities, then get(clazz,id) could execute more than one SQL statements. 2) If you have lazy loading, then it is possible that not all statements are executed when you get the entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable Hibernate Statistics in **persistence.xml**

```
<property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
```

Then use `SessionFactory.getStatistics()` and access necessary statiscits (probably `getQueries()`).

For more info see Hibernate Statistics docs [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/api/org/hibernate/stat/Statistics.html) or [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/stat/Statistics.html) or [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818070/hibernate-executed-queries-and-testing).

**EDIT**:

If you want to do it without logging, you'll have to use JDBC driver proxy, for example [log4jdbc](https://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/), [p6spy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p6spy/) or [jdbc-trace-wrapper](https://code.google.com/p/jdbc-trace-wrapper/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [show_sql, format_sql, and use_sql_comments](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-display-generated-sql-to-console-show_sql-format_sql-and-use_sql_comments/) to get the actually sql statements, in the log. [Append the log to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619160/sample-xml-configuration-for-log4j-have-a-main-java-application-and-want-to-w) and [parse the log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327073/parse-a-log4j-log-file) using whatever tool you choose. And now, Bob's your uncle.