# How does Hibernate generate sql string from session.get queries

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria, hibernate-session

I am using Hibernate 4.2.4 and I am interested to know how Hibernate translate a session.get call to an equivalent sql query that is eventually used to retrieve rows from database. I do not want to log the generated sql in console. I want to use the same sql query in my application. Something like below.

```
...
SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.buildServiceRegistry());

// I want the query string here
String query = sessionFactory.someUnknownMethod(Some Paramters);

Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
// actual session.get query
Comment comment = (Comment) session.get(Comment.class, new Integer(1));
...
```

I have seen this thread for Criteria query -> [How to get SQL from Hibernate Criteria API (*not* for logging)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/554481/how-to-get-sql-from-hibernate-criteria-api-not-for-logging).
I would like to know if similar procedure exists for session.get type queries.

I have also seen this thread -> [get SQL from hibernate get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501084/get-sql-from-hibernate-get)
where the question is exactly same as mine, but the accepted solution talks about fetching statistics which, to my understanding, only accounts for the queries that have already been executed. Plus, from statistics I was able to catch hql/sql queries but not session.get queries.

I want to know if there is a way for a user to generate and use the sql even before the actual session.get gets executed (possibly by following the same path as hibernate).

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554481/how-to-get-sql-from-hibernate-criteria-api-not-for-logging